# Weight sum partitioning of undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, partitioning

Given an undirected graph *G(N,E)* with weighted edges and a maximum weights sum value *s*, what is a good algorithm to partition *G*'s *N* nodes into subsets that are connected by edges whose sum is less than *s*?

Simple example: Let *s=10* and *G*

```
A <-2-> B <-3-> C <-12-> D <-9-> E <-21-> F <-40-> G <-1-> H,
```

then the algorithm would split the nodes in the following groups

```
{A,B,C}, {D,E}, {F}, {G,H}.
```

Of course this gets harder as when the graph has multiple cycles and that lead to multiple choices. I am currently applying the greedy approach of following the first edge and stopping just before the sum goes above *s*. This is usually good, but there are some obviously poor choices like in the following example

```
A <-9-> B <-1-> C <-3-> D <-2-> E,
```

where the greedy method (for *s=10*) would pick

```
{A,B}, {C,D,E}
```

but I would like

```
{A}, {B,C,D,E}
```

because B,C,D,E obviously form a tighter group. So maybe this sort of grouping implies minimal sets as suggested in comments, I don't know.

Comment: Do you mean 'minimum' number of partitions needed?

Comment: No, I don't care about the total number of partitions. Actually I would prefer that the subsets have similar cardinality.

Comment: What do you want to do in the case of `A <-6-> B <-6-> C` for `s=10`?

Comment: That is one of the problems I am having with cycles. Currently I choose the first pair {A,B}, {C}, but that might be suboptimal.

Comment: I have updated my question to include a counter-example that might shed more light in what I'm after.

Comment: should F be in the G and H in your first example? It looks like that could have a 5-weight subset.

Comment: You are correct, F was wrongly placed. I wanted to show sets of one element so I corrected the weight instead. Thanks!

Comment: I think that if you had an answer for this you'd have an answer for the Knapsack Problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem Imagine a star topology. Your highest-scoring group would be the optimal knapsack. I think yours is a generalization of that problem. Oh, also even if you picked the globally lowest value you still might have a bad split.